# pgx in a goroutine reporting connection busy

Tags: postgresql, go

My application is using `pgx` to running database queries in a goroutines. However, I am getting connection busy errors. Is there a way to have a goroutine

```
func writeDb(dbconn *pgx.Conn) {
   sqlWritePost := `QUERY_HERE`
   _, err := dbconn.Exec(context.Background(), sqlWritePost, v.Url, v.Content, v.StrippedContent, v.Posthash)
   if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
       os.Exit(1)
    }
}

func main() {

   var dbconn *pgx.Conn
   dbconn, err := pgx.Connect(context.Background(), os.Getenv("database_string"))
   if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
       os.Exit(1)
   }
   ...
   go writeDb(dbconn)
   ...

}
```

I am receiving errors `conn busy`. Is there a way to structure my code to avoid this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: It is perfectly normal to use the DB in a goroutine, otherwise it would be useless for an HTTP server, for instance. Errors like this are typically caused by not calling [Rows.Close](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Close).

Comment: I am not capturing a rows value. My understanding that is from the Query() function, no?

Comment: My mistake, I didn't look closely enough. ["`*pgx.Conn` represents a single connection to the database and is not concurrency safe. Use sub-package pgxpool for a concurrency safe connection pool."](https://godoc.org/github.com/jackc/pgx#pkg-index)